# Overleaf Appendix Table Numbering

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am using overleaf to write a journal article and want to move a lot of my results table to the Appendix. So I write the following commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  



\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\appendix

\section{Tables}

\begin{table}[!]
\begin{scriptsize}

\centering
\caption{Reduced Form Estimates using Linear Probability Model}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
\hline
\hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
VARIABLES & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
&&&& \\
&&&& \\
&&&& \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Note:}Robust standard errors in parentheses *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1 }
\end{tabular}

\end{scriptsize} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

While the section is recognized as appendix and tables, the numbering of the tables continue from the main text. How do I go from for example: Table 12 to Table A1?

Thanks

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Hello, I have made a reproducible example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
```

to change the numbering style of the appendix tables

Please also note that `scriptsize` is NOT an environment, it is a macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage[para,online,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}  



\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\begin{table}[htbp]
%\begin{scriptsize}
\scriptsize
\centering
\caption{Reduced Form Estimates using Linear Probability Model}
\label{tab:my-table-}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
\hline
\hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
VARIABLES & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
&&&& \\
&&&& \\
&&&& \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Note:}Robust standard errors in parentheses *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1 }
\end{tabular}

%\end{scriptsize} 
\end{table}

\appendix
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}

\section{Tables}

\begin{table}[htbp]
%\begin{scriptsize}
\scriptsize
\centering
\caption{Reduced Form Estimates using Linear Probability Model}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
\hline
\hline
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
VARIABLES & A & B & C & D \\
\hline
&&&& \\
&&&& \\
&&&& \\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Note:}Robust standard errors in parentheses *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1 }
\end{tabular}

%\end{scriptsize} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```